# What is the effect used here that resembles a distorted guitar?

Tags: guitar, synthesizer, synthesis

I am building a project for my music technology module in University and would like to know how to imitate this effect. Originally, I thought it was guitar but after having watched a video of the band playing it live, I realized that it was the synth player in action over the solo. There are two songs that feature this effect, both of which have solos that I have pasted below:

[The Midnight - Comeback Kid](https://youtu.be/YO_spdAYjPk?t=212)
[The Midnight - Collateral](https://youtu.be/x--rvICd6Ac?t=146)
['Collateral'' Live Version](https://youtu.be/HsnE3aW3CZk?t=218)

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me out. I don't play snyth but I would love to know how to get this sound.

Answer (score 0):

This just sounds like using a normal distortion effect on the synth. It maybe had it built in, or they may use an actual guitar pedal. Moist modern synths have distortion of various types. Experiment.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a distortion effect like Rory Alsop mentioned.

On synths there are a lot of ways to achieve this:

- In case the synth does not have effects:

  - You can increase the volume to get digital distortion. This sounds really bad (not like a guitar-ish effect).
  - Use a guitar distortion pedal
  - Use an external effect processor
- In case the synth has effects:

  - Some synths (very rare though) have a built-in tube to get a distorted sound.
  - Mostly there is a default distortion effect.
  - On some modern synths there are guitar speaker cabinet simulators which can simulate a distorted sound.

Answer (score 0):

In the Softare FL Studio you get FL Slayer and you can also install other VSTs like LABS (free) or AmpleGuitar SC (paid) that include electric guitar sounds like in this demo: